# How to run and connect two nestjs grpc microservices on the same machine

Tags: microservices, grpc, nestjs

I'm creating Grpc microservices with nestjs. How can i connect both servers on my localhost.

I have tried using ngrok to create a tunnel for one of the service but i'm still getting errors **"address in use"** and **"No address added out of total 2 resolved"** even though both are running on different ports

first service

```
import { authServiceOptions } from './auth/grpc/auth.options';
import { notificationClientServiceOptions } from '../../notification/src/notification/grpc/notification.options';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api/v1/services');

  // Services
  app.connectMicroservice(notificationClientServiceOptions);
  app.connectMicroservice(authServiceOptions);

  await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();
  await app.listen(51700);
}
bootstrap();
```

second service

```
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { notificationServiceOptions } from './notification/grpc/notification.options';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api/v1/services');

  // Services
  app.connectMicroservice(notificationServiceOptions);

  await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();
  await app.listen(3001);
}
bootstrap();
```

// client options for second service

```
export const notificationClientServiceOptions: ClientOptions = {
  transport: Transport.GRPC,
  options: {
    url: 'https://b6a4cd09.ngrok.io/',
    package: 'notification',
    protoPath: join(__dirname, './notification.proto'),
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! Turns out i was specifying a **http** url for a **Grpc** service. This is the correct client option for the second service.

```
export const notificationClientServiceOptions: ClientOptions = {
  transport: Transport.GRPC,
  options: {
    // you can specify any port that is not in use (just don't prefix it with 'http')
    url: 'localhost:5500', 
    package: 'notification',
    protoPath: join(__dirname, './notification.proto'),
  },
};
```

Also i looked up into the source code for nestjs. Turns out the default url for any microservice is **localhost:5000** hence if your are running more than one service it's best to specify the url for each service.

Another problem i ran into was connecting the microservices;
If the services are located in two separate nestjs projects you don't need to use `app.connectMicroservice(secondServiceOptions)` in the `firstService` this is because `await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync()` would attempt to start both services but it'll fail. This is because the `secondService` is already running in a separate project.

To connect to the `secondService` from the `firstService` use the `@Client(secondServiceOptions)` decorator.